# Does the state of UI control the URL or does the URL control the state of the UI?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, web-deployment

Which is better practice?

Currently, one of the components of my React JS app only listens to the URL during initial render of the APP.

After the initial, the state of the UI of this component will set the URL and it will no longer listen to the URL. It is designed this way because the user is only supposed to modify the URL during initially loading of the APP.

Is this standard practice in industry web development?:

To have the UI first modify state and then to have the state modify the URL rather than having the UI first modify the URL and then the URL to modify the state?